# Why doesn't getblockchaininfo reveal BIP9 signaling statistics?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, segregated-witness, bip9-version-bits

An example of the output of `getblockchaininfo` is here:

https://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/getblockchaininfo

The `softforks` field describes the number of required / found blocks signaling the soft fork, but the `bip9_softforks` field does not. It just indicates a generic status message ("defined", "started", "locked_in", "active", "failed").

Is there an RPC command that will return the number of SegWit blocks?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty boring. Nobody did the work to implement it (yet).

Comment: Works for me :-)
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/9571